# Parametric point on hyperbola

Tags: conic-sections

The parametric point on hyperbola is $(a\sec\theta, b\tan\theta)$.

Why is that when the parametric angle $\theta$ is in 1st quadrant, it represents the part of hyperbola in 1st quadrant, and similarly for the 4th quadrant, but in the 2nd and 3rd quadrants the angle $\theta$ and the part of hyperbola it represents get interchanged?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Thanks, I'm new here.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! ... The reason that the parametric angle and the corresponding part of the hyperbola get interchanged is simply that $\tan\theta$ (the point's $y$-coordinate) is *negative* for $\theta$ in the second quadrant, and *positive* for $\theta$ in the third quadrant. ... Generally, there's no requirement that the geometry of a parameter match the geometry of the curve being drawn. For instance, we can parameterize a *complete* unit circle via $(\cos10\theta, \sin10\theta)$, while parameter $\theta$ itself only varies from $0^\circ$ to $36^\circ$.

Comment: @Blue yep, got it. Thanks.

Comment: @StutiGupta: As a bit of a follow-up to my comments to [your other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4808450/409) ... Note that, with the hyperbola parameterization $(a\sec\theta,b\tan\theta)$, as $\theta$ approaches, reaches, and passes $90^\circ$, the parameterized point approaches, "reaches", and "passes through, coming back from the other side of" the point-at-infinity of one of the asymptotes; likewise for $270^\circ$. So, the weird quadrant-swapping behavior you've asked about is precisely what causes the parameterization to trace the hyperbola as a "continuous loop".

Comment: @Blue thank you for your help